# Как учесть высоту header при переходе якоря?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, css3

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#menu").on("click", "a", function(event) {
    //отменяем стандартную обработку нажатия по ссылке
    event.preventDefault();

    //забираем идентификатор бока с атрибута href
    var id = $(this).attr('href'),

      //узнаем высоту от начала страницы до блока на который ссылается якорь
      top = $(id).offset().top;

    //анимируем переход на расстояние - top за 1500 мс
    $('body,html').animate({
      scrollTop: top
    }, 1500);
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font: normal 14px/130% arial, verdana;
}

a,
a:hover {
  color: #FFF;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#wrapper {
  padding-top: 150px;
}

#inner-wrapper {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#header {
  height: 150px;
  width: 960px;
  background: #069;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}

#header h1 {
  font-size: 32px;
  line-height: 36px;
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 70px 0 0 30px;
  margin: 0 0 14px;
}

#content {
  min-height: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 20px 5%;
  color: #000;
  border: 1px solid #f0f0f0;
  border-width: 0 1px
}

#footer {
  background: #f0f0f0;
  height: 25px;
  color: #777;
  padding: 10px;
}

#menu {
  background: #000;
}

#menu>ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

#menu>ul:after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  line-height: 0;
  height: 0;
  width: 100%;
  clear: both;
}

#menu>ul>li {
  float: left;
}

#menu>ul>li+li {
  margin-left: 5px;
}

#menu>ul>li>a {
  display: block;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  color: #FFF;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s;
  -moz-transition: all .3s;
  -ms-transition: all .3s;
  -o-transition: all .3s;
  transition: all .3s;
}

#menu>ul>li>a:hover {
  background: #E76600;
}

.post {
  width: 30%;
  margin-right: 5%;
  float: left;
  text-align: justify;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.post.last {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.post .post-title {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

#ex2 .post,
#ex3 .post,
#ex4 .post {
  width: 45%;
  margin-right: 10%;
}

#ex2 .post.last,
#ex3 .post.last,
#ex4 .post.last {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.separator {
  clear: both;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 50px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:960px) {
  #inner-wrapper {
    width: 80%;
  }
}


/* Back to top button */

#back-to-top {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999;
  display: none;
  bottom: 70px;
  right: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#back-to-top i {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  background: #26ADE4;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 50px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-transition: .3s all;
  -moz-transition: .3s all;
  -ms-transition: .3s all;
  -o-transition: .3s all;
  transition: .3s all;
}

#back-to-top i:hover {
  background: #333;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Back to Top button</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="inner-wrapper">
      <header id="header">
        <h1>WebComplex</h1>
        <nav id="menu">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#ex1">Link #1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#ex2">Link #2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#ex3">Link #3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#ex4">Link #4</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </header>
      <div id="content">
        <section id="ex1">
          <h2>Block with ID="ex1"</h2>
          <article class="post">
            <h3 class="post-title">Post title</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
              irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
          </article>
          <article class="post">
            <h3 class="post-title">Post title</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
              irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
          </article>
          <article class="post last">
            <h3 class="post-title">Post title</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
              irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
          </article>
          <article class="post">
            <h3 class="post-title">Post title</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
              irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
          </article>
          <article class="post">
            <h3 class="post-title">Post title</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
              irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
          </article>
          <article class="post last">
            <h3 class="post-title">Post title</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
              irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
          </article>
          <article class="post">
            <h3 class="post-title">Post title</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
              irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
          </article>
          <article class="post">
            <h3 class="post-title">Post title</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
              irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
          </article>
          <article class="post last">
            <h3 class="post-title">Post title</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
              irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
          </article>
        </section>
        <div class="separator"></div>
        <section id="ex2">
          <h2>Block with ID="ex2"</h2>
          <article class="post">
            <h3 class="post-title">Post title</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
              irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
              irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
          </article>
          <article class="post last">
            <h3 class="post-title">Post title</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
              irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
              irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
          </article>
        </section>
        <div class="separator"></div>
        <section id="ex3">
          <h2>Block with ID="ex3"</h2>
          <article class="post">
            <h3 class="post-title">Post title</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
              irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
              irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
          </article>
          <article class="post last">
            <h3 class="post-title">Post title</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
              irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
              irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
          </article>
        </section>
        <div class="separator"></div>
        <section id="ex4">
          <h2>Block with ID="ex4"</h2>
          <article class="post">
            <h3 class="post-title">Post title</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
              irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
              irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
          </article>
          <article class="post last">
            <h3 class="post-title">Post title</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
              irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
              irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
          </article>
        </section>
      </div>
      <footer id="footer">WebComplex &copy 2014</footer>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#menu").on("click", "a", function(event) {
    //отменяем стандартную обработку нажатия по ссылке
    event.preventDefault();

    //забираем идентификатор бока с атрибута href
    var id = $(this).attr('href'),

    // узнаем высоту header
    offset = $('header').outerHeight(),
    
      //узнаем высоту от начала страницы до блока на который ссылается якорь
      top = $(id).offset().top - offset;

    //анимируем переход на расстояние - top за 1500 мс
    $('body,html').animate({
      scrollTop: top
    }, 1500);
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font: normal 14px/130% arial, verdana;
}

a,
a:hover {
  color: #FFF;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#wrapper {
  padding-top: 150px;
}

#inner-wrapper {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#header {
  height: 150px;
  width: 960px;
  background: #069;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}

#header h1 {
  font-size: 32px;
  line-height: 36px;
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 70px 0 0 30px;
  margin: 0 0 14px;
}

#content {
  min-height: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 20px 5%;
  color: #000;
  border: 1px solid #f0f0f0;
  border-width: 0 1px
}

#footer {
  background: #f0f0f0;
  height: 25px;
  color: #777;
  padding: 10px;
}

#menu {
  background: #000;
}

#menu>ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

#menu>ul:after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  line-height: 0;
  height: 0;
  width: 100%;
  clear: both;
}

#menu>ul>li {
  float: left;
}

#menu>ul>li+li {
  margin-left: 5px;
}

#menu>ul>li>a {
  display: block;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  color: #FFF;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s;
  -moz-transition: all .3s;
  -ms-transition: all .3s;
  -o-transition: all .3s;
  transition: all .3s;
}

#menu>ul>li>a:hover {
  background: #E76600;
}

.post {
  width: 30%;
  margin-right: 5%;
  float: left;
  text-align: justify;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.post.last {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.post .post-title {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

#ex2 .post,
#ex3 .post,
#ex4 .post {
  width: 45%;
  margin-right: 10%;
}

#ex2 .post.last,
#ex3 .post.last,
#ex4 .post.last {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.separator {
  clear: both;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 50px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:960px) {
  #inner-wrapper {
    width: 80%;
  }
}


/* Back to top button */

#back-to-top {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999;
  display: none;
  bottom: 70px;
  right: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#back-to-top i {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  background: #26ADE4;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 50px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-transition: .3s all;
  -moz-transition: .3s all;
  -ms-transition: .3s all;
  -o-transition: .3s all;
  transition: .3s all;
}

#back-to-top i:hover {
  background: #333;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Back to Top button</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="inner-wrapper">
      <header id="header">
        <h1>WebComplex</h1>
        <nav id="menu">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#ex1">Link #1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#ex2">Link #2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#ex3">Link #3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#ex4">Link #4</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </header>
      <div id="content">
        <section id="ex1">
          <h2>Block with ID="ex1"</h2>
          <article class="post">
            <h3 class="post-title">Post title</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
              irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
          </article>
          <article class="post">
            <h3 class="post-title">Post title</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
              irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
          </article>
          <article class="post last">
            <h3 class="post-title">Post title</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
              irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
          </article>
          <article class="post">
            <h3 class="post-title">Post title</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
              irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
          </article>
          <article class="post">
            <h3 class="post-title">Post title</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
              irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
          </article>
          <article class="post last">
            <h3 class="post-title">Post title</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
              irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
          </article>
          <article class="post">
            <h3 class="post-title">Post title</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
              irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
          </article>
          <article class="post">
            <h3 class="post-title">Post title</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
              irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
          </article>
          <article class="post last">
            <h3 class="post-title">Post title</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
              irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
          </article>
        </section>
        <div class="separator"></div>
        <section id="ex2">
          <h2>Block with ID="ex2"</h2>
          <article class="post">
            <h3 class="post-title">Post title</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
              irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
              irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
          </article>
          <article class="post last">
            <h3 class="post-title">Post title</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
              irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
              irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
          </article>
        </section>
        <div class="separator"></div>
        <section id="ex3">
          <h2>Block with ID="ex3"</h2>
          <article class="post">
            <h3 class="post-title">Post title</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
              irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
              irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
          </article>
          <article class="post last">
            <h3 class="post-title">Post title</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
              irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
              irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
          </article>
        </section>
        <div class="separator"></div>
        <section id="ex4">
          <h2>Block with ID="ex4"</h2>
          <article class="post">
            <h3 class="post-title">Post title</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
              irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
              irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
          </article>
          <article class="post last">
            <h3 class="post-title">Post title</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
              irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
              irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
          </article>
        </section>
      </div>
      <footer id="footer">WebComplex &copy 2014</footer>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```